# Spring Boot doc is out of date

Tags: spring-boot

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

This is out of date as far as I can tell.

The github repo didn't exist so I used the initilizr mentioned beforehand and imported that into intellij.

then I tried creating a new java class like the first part of the tutorial says in https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/#_create_a_simple_web_application

but straight out the bat, the imports in the provided code fail :

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }

}
```

I googled around a bit and apparently (but I'm probably misunderstanding.) `RestController` is deprecated in favor of `Controller`?

what about `RequestMapping` then?

how do I set up a basic test rest service.

PS:  in the initilizr (https://start.spring.io/), I chose Spring Boot 2.0.0 M6

Comment: You either use `@RestController` OR `@RequestMapping` in combination with `@Controller` as `@RestController` is marked with `@ResponseBody` and `@Controller` internally and is thus already eligible for component scanning. It's just cleaner to use `@RestController`.

Comment: Must be an issue on your side then... Github repo is present here... And your understanding is wrong about `@RestController`.

Comment: huh. the git pull failed so I assumed the repo didn't exist but yeah it's there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `pom.xml` file, change : the very first `<artifactId>` line to :

```
<artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
```

it might have been something different (for me it was `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>`).

with this you imports should be available.